# Should I suggest to have the bounty un-awarded to myself?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, accepted-answer, bountied-tab

It appears that if a bounty is clicked as awarded, even if the time still remains (e.g., for a better answer), then the question goes away from the "featured" tab.

Is it a safe (and a good idea, too) to ask the person to un-award the bounty from my answer, still having them keep it accepted, in order to get more votes from passerby's, or is there a risk of the full bounty no longer being automatically awarded in full to an eligible answer that's been accepted, due to the manual award/un-award step that'd take place?

Comment: There is no way to revoke awarding a bounty short of involving a mod, or maybe even only a dev. So this is not actually possible as outlined.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I'm 98% sure that mods can do it.

Comment: @Mithrandir why the 2%?

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of the `featured` tab is to get more/better help for the OP.

So, once the OP is satisfied with the answer and has awarded a bounty (and also having accepted the answer), there is no point in having that question still in the "featured" tab.

Asking the OP to stall on the bounty award, just for the passer-by's votes isn't really a good practise(IMHO).

Comment: the thing is -- answers that are ACCEPTED, even after the start of the bounty, still show up in FEATURED.  I believe the mistake is with the AWARDED ones that don't -- otherwise, if you change the behaviour for ACCEPTED, then even experienced users will stop accepting, and then you'll never know whether they'll remember to award the bounty or not.

Comment: I get it. I'm just saying that asking the user to stall the bounty award wouldn't be a great practise, cause the OP might forget about the qn, as it's solved. And the qn might remain unanswered :)

Answer (score 1):

> There is no way to revoke awarding a bounty short of involving a mod, or maybe even only a dev. So this is not actually possible as outlined. – Nathan Tuggy 4 hours ago